# Merging lists of different sizes in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have 2 lists

`s = [1 2 3 4 5]`

and

`p = [:a :b :c :d :e :f :h :i :j :k :l :m]`

I would like to take N elements from p where N is a random number between 1 to K and create a mapping from s to these N elements from p.

the resulting mapping could be something like

`((1 :a) (1 :b) (1 :c) (2 :d) (2 :e) (3 :f) (4 :h) (4 :i) (5 :j) (5 :k) (5 :l))`

for K=3.

it's fine if not all the elements in p are used but there are enough elements to cover the case where N is max for all elements in s.

I've come up with this but it's missing the take random N elements part and assigns an (almost) equal number of elements to each element in s

`(partition 2 (interleave (cycle s) (shuffle p))))`

this results in

`((1 :d) (2 :f) (3 :h) (4 :e) (5 :l) (1 :b) (2 :k) (3 :a) (4 :j) (5 :g) (1 :i) (2 :c) (3 :m))`

**UPDATE:**
Let me add some more context to the question for a better understanding.
I'm trying to generate a galaxy where each star will have 1 to N planets in it's system. The s list contains the ids of the stars, and the p list contains the ids of planets. I would like to map planet ids to star ids so each system has 1 to N random planets in the system.

Comment: It's not clear for me how you would like to map elements from s to p. I am also not sure if your first example is correct. You wrote: "I would like to take N elements from p where N is a random number between 1 to K and create a mapping from s to these N elements from p." but then you are stating that K=3, not N=3. How your first example results is constrained by the 3 random elements from p as it contains 11 distinct elements (`:a` to `:l`)?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl what I mean is I select a random number from 1 to K, say for K = 3 I got 2. Then I select 2 elements from p and create a mapping from the first element in s to these 2 elements. Then I would discard these to elements from p and do the same procedure for the next element in s and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly:

```
(def s [1 2 3 4 5])
(def p [:a :b :c :d :e :f :h :i :j :k :l :m])
(def k 3)

;; concatenate corresponding elements from two sequences into 2-element vectors
(map vector
     ;; generate a sequence of elements from s each duplicated 1 to k times
     (mapcat #(repeat (inc (rand-int k)) %) s)
     ;; generate infinite shuffled seq of elements from p
     (cycle (shuffle p)))
```

Example output:

```
([1 :f] [2 :j] [2 :b] [3 :m] [3 :a] [4 :i] [5 :l] [5 :c] [5 :e])
```

Comment: You should probably remove the `cycle`, as you can't assign a planet to more than one star (see question UPDATE).

Comment: This update doesn't indicate to me that we should cycle but if that's what OP needs then you're right.

Comment: There is a problem in your solution. You can output a seq with less items than p

Answer (score 0):

Each star must have a random number of planets. Here at least 1 but maximum of 3:

```
(def stars [1 2 3 4 5])
(def planets [:a :b :c :d :e :f :h :i :j :k :l :m])

(let [max-num-planets 3
      solar-systems (mapcat #(repeat (inc (rand-int max-num-planets)) %) stars)]
  (map #(list %1 %2) solar-systems (shuffle planets))
```

Every time you run it the answer will be different, but each star will be included as each star has between 1 and 3 planets. Example outputs:

```
;; ((1 :a) (1 :b) (1 :c) (2 :d) (2 :e) (3 :f) (4 :h) (4 :i) (4 :j) (5 :k) (5:l) (5 :m))
;; ((1 :a) (1 :b) (1 :c) (2 :d) (3 :e) (3 :f) (4 :h) (5 :i))
```

Not all the planets are always used, and a planet is never repeated - because of course a planet can't exist in more than one solar system.

Comment: this results in the same number of p-elements for each s-element (3 for each)

Comment: Comment above is no longer relevant - was before OP gave us the context - that this is about assigning planets to stars, where each star has a random number of planets.